# how to get the bundle values in onrestart when the activity is brought to front

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle

I have a doubt,

I have started my acitivity with the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, so first time oncreate() will be called, if the activity already exists in the history stack then onrestart() will be called.

So first time I am putting some extras in the intent, in oncreate i can get the bundle values, when i try to get the bundle in onrestart when the activity is brought to front, I am not able to get the newly bundled values.

how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your question clearly.

Anyway, if you just need to access extras in new intent, try overridding the Activity.onNewIntent(Intent) method.

If you need to access extras in savedInstanceState, try overridding the Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle) method instead of onRestart() since it is always called after onRestart() method.